# Human annotation tool for corpora in NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to build my own training corpus for Named Entity Recognition, but I don't know if there is already an existing tool for this or if I have to implement one myself.

Basically, what I need to do is take a corpus and manually tag it word by word, which is pretty tedious, but it has to be done.

Can anyone tell me if there is already an existing one and where to get it?

Comment: This kind of question not encouraged here in SO. Please provide details of what are your looking for and what have you tried so far.

Comment: I think this type of question is now supposed to go on SoftwareRecs. Here's a semi-related answer I gave there which might help: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/9757/5221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a good experience working with [BRAT](http://brat.nlplab.org/).
GATE is also a very complex tool for annotating, steeper learning curve.

Comment: Thanks! Brat was a pretty useful tool. I just have one doubt: how can I tell Brat that two words belong to the same entity? For instance, I want to tell it that United States is the same entity as U.S.A. Is there any way to do it on Brat? Because I can't find the answer in the manual.

Comment: You can try the correference style annotation, like here: http://weaver.nlplab.org/~brat/demo/latest/#/not-editable/BioNLP-ST_2011_coreference_development_data/PMID-9989503

Answer (score 2):

We had a nice experience using [DataTurks](https://dataturks.com) . They provide nice intuitive UI which allows to add collaborator, insights into data, leaderboard for annotators and some other funky features.

https://dataturks.com

Answer (score 1):

For online annotation of text or HTML corpus of relatively short documents I also recommend [BRAT](http://brat.nlplab.org/). You will have to go under the hood of the python web application if you want to do anything custom. It also failed to work for me on large HTML documents (100 or so pages).

I have also used stand-alone apps:

- Protege + [Knowtator](http://knowtator.sourceforge.net/): a bit cumbersome to setup / use, but it
  works;
- [Gate](https://gate.ac.uk/): also cumbersome, and it somewhat works. Backup
  your annotations at regular intervals as you might get
  surprised by a stacktrace that also wiped or corrupted your annotated
  corpus (which is just serialized Java objects).

If you are dealing with PDF documents, we built a web-based PDF Annotation Tool: [NOTA](http://language.ai/nota.html). It accepts anything printed to PDF, including scans. We do commercial OCR on our end to recover text from images. There is a REST API to create color-coded annotation schemas and pre-populate documents with annotations, as well as a REST API for exporting formatted text and annotation offsets. There is also a JS API you can use to customize any annotation workflows, add metadata to annotations, etc. Relationships are not supported out of the box. Large documents, 200+ pages are supported. [Email us](http://language.ai/#contact) and we can give you an API key to try it out. Details and documentation links can be found [here](http://language.ai/nota.html). It is free for small research projects.

Here is a screenshot of what the annotations looks like :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I co-develop myself the **web-based text annotation tool**: [tagtog.net](https://www.tagtog.net/)

There is **nothing to install**, and you can define the type of **entities** you want to annotate. Additionally you can annotation **relationships, document labels**, and much more. You can upload your documents in many different formats, including **PDF or markdown**. You can annotate together with your **team collaboratively**. We have put great care in making the interface **easy and beautiful**. It looks like this:

[image]

You can start right away with a [**free account**](https://www.tagtog.net/). Also I would be happy to help you with any doubt or issue you may have; just ping me or write us an email to the address shown on the website, [tagtog.net](https://www.tagtog.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Our annotation tool [Prodigy](http://prodi.gy) is very scriptable, and is designed for active learning. It integrates especially well with our NLP library [spaCy](http://spacy.io).

We've paid particular attention to the Named Entity Recogntion (NER) annotation workflows, as entity recognition can otherwise be very slow. I have a tutorial video on this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4scwf8KeIA

Answer (score 0):

There is this tool called, Dataturks is super simple to use, fully online [NLP annotation tool](https://dataturks.com), so that I even can easily push my teammates to complete datasets for our projects.

Answer (score 0):

try [TagEditor](https://github.com/d5555/TagEditor) , 
It is a desktop application designed to annotate text for training with spaCy library.
You can tag Named Entities, Dependencies, Parts of speech, text categories
 and print json file.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS3Bu.jpg)